# Python Scrape H2 and Price with Selenium

Tags: python, web-scraping, jupyter-notebook

Im trying to scrape a Product Name and Product Price from this html

```
<div class="product-info">
    <div class="left">
        <div class="image a_bossthemes"><a href="/image/cache/data/spigen/airpods-pro/shine-shield/spigenairpodsproshineshieldmetallicsilver1-700x700.jpg" title="" class="colorbox cboxElement"><img src="/image/cache/data/spigen/airpods-pro/shine-shield/spigenairpodsproshineshieldmetallicsilver1-228x228.jpg" title="" alt="" id="image"></a></div>
              <div class="image-additional a_bossthemes">
    <div class="es-carousel">
      <ul class="skin-opencart" style="width: 496px; margin-left: 0px;">
                    <li style="margin-right: 8px; width: 73px;"><div class="boss-image-add"><a href="/image/cache/data/spigen/airpods-pro/shine-shield/spigenairpodsproshineshieldmetallicsilver7-700x700.jpg" title="" class="colorbox cboxElement"><img src="/image/cache/data/spigen/airpods-pro/shine-shield/spigenairpodsproshineshieldmetallicsilver7-74x74.jpg" title="" alt=""></a></div></li>
                    <li style="margin-right: 8px; width: 73px;"><div class="boss-image-add"><a href="/image/cache/data/spigen/airpods-pro/shine-shield/spigenairpodsproshineshieldmetallicsilver6-700x700.jpg" title="" class="colorbox cboxElement"><img src="/image/cache/data/spigen/airpods-pro/shine-shield/spigenairpodsproshineshieldmetallicsilver6-74x74.jpg" title="" alt=""></a></div></li>
                    <li style="margin-right: 8px; width: 73px;"><div class="boss-image-add"><a href="/image/cache/data/spigen/airpods-pro/shine-shield/spigenairpodsproshineshieldmetallicsilver5-700x700.jpg" title="" class="colorbox cboxElement"><img src="/image/cache/data/spigen/airpods-pro/shine-shield/spigenairpodsproshineshieldmetallicsilver5-74x74.jpg" title="" alt=""></a></div></li>
                    <li style="margin-right: 8px; width: 73px;"><div class="boss-image-add"><a href="/image/cache/data/spigen/airpods-pro/shine-shield/spigenairpodsproshineshieldmetallicsilver4-700x700.jpg" title="" class="colorbox cboxElement"><img src="/image/cache/data/spigen/airpods-pro/shine-shield/spigenairpodsproshineshieldmetallicsilver4-74x74.jpg" title="" alt=""></a></div></li>
                    <li style="margin-right: 8px; width: 73px;"><div class="boss-image-add"><a href="/image/cache/data/spigen/airpods-pro/shine-shield/spigenairpodsproshineshieldmetallicsilver3-700x700.jpg" title="" class="colorbox cboxElement"><img src="/image/cache/data/spigen/airpods-pro/shine-shield/spigenairpodsproshineshieldmetallicsilver3-74x74.jpg" title="" alt=""></a></div></li>
                    <li style="margin-right: 8px; width: 73px;"><div class="boss-image-add"><a href="/image/cache/data/spigen/airpods-pro/shine-shield/spigenairpodsproshineshieldmetallicsilver2-700x700.jpg" title="" class="colorbox cboxElement"><img src="/image/cache/data/spigen/airpods-pro/shine-shield/spigenairpodsproshineshieldmetallicsilver2-74x74.jpg" title="" alt=""></a></div></li>
                  </ul>
    </div>
  <div class="es-nav"><span class="es-nav-prev" style="display: none;">Previous</span><span class="es-nav-next">Next</span></div></div>
      </div>
    <div class="right">
  <div class="description">
    <h2>Anti Dust Sticker Apple AirPods Pro Spigen Shine Shield - Metallic Silver (2 Sets)</h2>
            <span>- Brand:</span> <a href="/spigen">Spigen</a><br>
            <span>- Product Code:</span> SGP-780<br>
    <span>- Weight:</span> 0.10 kg<br>
            <span>- Ready:</span> <span class="Ready">Ready </span></div>
        <div class="price">Price:                <span class="price-first">Rp.225,000</span>
                                    
                  </div>
```

I tried using find elements by tag name, class name and xpath but it didnt work.

this is the script i used

```
def getData(url):

driver.get(url)

names = driver.find_elements_by_tag_name("h2")
names_list = names[0].find_elements_by_xpath(".//*")
name = names_list[0].text
prices = driver.find_elements_by_class_name("price-first")
price = prices[4].text[3:]

return name, description, price
```

Anyone can help me how to make it works ? with some explanation so i can fix the problem.

Comment: Mind sharing the url you're scraping?

Comment: here's the url [link](https://www.unomax.com/apple/anti-dust-sticker-apple-airpods-pro-spigen-shine-shield-metallic-silver-2-sets.html)

Comment: im trying to scrape the class product-info section

Comment: Have you checked the page source which your program is receiving? Speaking of, can you provide a [mcve]?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get product's name, price, and description try this:

```
import time

from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

options = Options()
options.headless = False
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)

url = "https://www.unomax.com/apple/anti-dust-sticker-apple-airpods-pro-spigen-shine-shield-metallic-silver-2-sets.html"
driver.get(url)
time.sleep(2)
element = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@class="right"]')
name = element.find_element_by_tag_name("h2").text
price = element.find_element_by_class_name("price").text
description = element.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@style="color: rgb(68, 68, 68); font-family: "]')

print(f"{name} - {price.replace('HARGA: ', '')}")
print(description.text)
driver.close()
```

Output:

```
ANTI DUST STICKER APPLE AIRPODS PRO SPIGEN SHINE SHIELD - METALLIC SILVER (2 SETS) - RP.225,000
Spigen Shine Shield Anti Dust Sticker merupakan sticker protector dengan material logam tipis yang dirancang khusus untuk mencegah debu menempel dan goresan pada AirPods Pro anda. Desain modern, simple dan pemasangannya pun sangat mudah dilakukan. Memiliki ketebalan hanya 0.04mm dan memiliki warna silver yang elegan memberikan perlindungan dan kemewahan pada AirPods Pro anda.
```